# How to validate all input fields, select options at a time on a form

Tags: java, validation

using below java Code, on server side validation I have successfully validated input fields and options...etc. but the problem is when I click on submit button, one by one error messages are  showing, but I wanted to show all the error messages at a time when I click on submit button. can anyone please tell me what are the changes should I make in below code to solve my problem.

```
1.Code
@Component
public UserValidation implements Validator 
{
    // @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

                return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
            }
            // @Override
            public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
                User user = (User) target;
                final String nameRegex = "[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)*";      
                final String phoneRegex = "^[6-9]\\d{9}$";
            
                if (user.getUserName().equals("")) {
                    errors.rejectValue("userrName", "userrName.required", "Error: User Name is required");
                    return;
                }
                
                if (user.getUserName().length() > 20) {
                    errors.rejectValue("userrName", "userrName.required", "Error: User Name reached maximum limit of characters allowed");
                    return;
                }

                if (user.getUserName().matches(nameRegex) == false) {
                    errors.rejectValue("userrName", "userrName.required", "Error: Invalid User Name ");
                    return;
                }
                
                if (user.getUserType().equals("0")) {
                    errors.rejectValue("userType", "userType.required", "Error: Select User Type");
                    return;
                }
                
                if (user.getUserNumber().equals("")) {
                    errors.rejectValue("userNumber", "userNumber.required", "Error: User Number is required");
                    return;
                }

                if (user.getUserNumber().matches(phoneRegex) == false) {
                    errors.rejectValue("userNumber", "userNumber.required", "Error: Invalid User Number ");
                    return;
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: If you don't want your method to return after adding an error, then you should not have a `return;` statement after adding an error

Answer (score 2):

Remove `return` in the if statements and only return once all the cases are tested.

`Errors` object stores `BindingErrors` and `Validation` errors of particular object ,so ideally you should push all validation errors to the error object before returning.

Comment: It works. but, the problem is, it returns both username is  required and invalid username at a time for one input field

Comment: You should rearrange your username validation, first check if username not empty ,then in nested if check legth and only if length is proper then do regex validation